# Ошибка при запуске сгенерированного в рантайме класса

Tags: java, рефлексия, runtime, javac, jna

Необходимо сгенерировать класс в рантайме и запустить его. Генерируется он без проблем, вот только при его загрузке ClassLoader`ом, создании его экземпляра и вызове метода main с помощью reflection выскакивает ошибка:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at JNATest.testMetod.main(testMetod.java:68)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: MyClass$CLibrary
    at MyClass.main(MyClass.java:13)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MyClass$CLibrary
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:530)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 6 more
```

Однако если создавать класс вручную в IDE, то его код выполняется без проблем. Судя по ошибке, проблема в интерфейсе, что внутри класса. Как можно решить проблему и запустить генерируемый код в рантайме при помощи reflection?

Код программы следующий:

```java
package JNATest;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.tools.Diagnostic;
import javax.tools.DiagnosticCollector;
import javax.tools.JavaCompiler;
import javax.tools.JavaFileObject;
import javax.tools.StandardJavaFileManager;
import javax.tools.ToolProvider;

public class testMetod {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException,
            IllegalAccessException {
        String fileName = "MyClass.java";
        String className = "MyClass.class";
        File[] f = new File[] { new File(fileName), new File(className) };
        for (File file : f)
            file.delete();

        BufferedWriter fos = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName));
        fos.write("import com.sun.jna.Library;\n" +
                "import com.sun.jna.Native;\n" +
                "import com.sun.jna.Platform;\n" +
                "\n" +
                "public class MyClass {\n" +
                "    public interface CLibrary extends Library {\n" +
                "        CLibrary INSTANCE = (CLibrary) Native.load(\n" +
                "                (Platform.isWindows() ? \"msvcrt\" : \"c\"), CLibrary.class);\n" +
                "        void printf(String format, Object... args);\n" +
                "    }\n" +
                "\n" +
                "    public static void main(String[] args) {\n" +
                "        CLibrary.INSTANCE.printf(\"Hello, World\\n\");\n" +
                "    }\n" +
                "\n" +
                "}");
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();

        JavaCompiler javac = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
        StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = javac.getStandardFileManager(null, null, null);
        DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject> diagnostics = new DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject>();
        Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> compilationUnits1 = fileManager.getJavaFileObjectsFromFiles(Arrays
                .asList(new File[] { new File(fileName) }));
        javac.getTask(null, fileManager, diagnostics, null, null, compilationUnits1).call();
        for (Diagnostic diagnostic : diagnostics.getDiagnostics())
            System.out.println(diagnostic);
        fileManager.close();


        try {
            MyClassLoader loader = new MyClassLoader();

            Class c = loader.getClassFromFile(new File(className));

            File file = new File("MyClass.class");

            Object o = c.newInstance();
            Method m = c.getMethod("main", new Class[] { String[].class });
            m.invoke(o, new Object[] { new String[0] });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }

    static class MyClassLoader extends ClassLoader {

        public Class getClassFromFile(File f) {
            byte[] raw = new byte[(int) f.length()];
            //System.out.println(f.length());
            InputStream in = null;
            try {
                in = new FileInputStream(f);
                in.read(raw);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                if (in != null)
                    in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return defineClass(null, raw, 0, raw.length);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При компиляции интерфейс перемещается в отдельный класс-файл. А у вас загружается только один файл. Не могу сказать с уверенностью - можно ли в вашей реализации загрузить оба. Попробуйте сначала интерфейс, потом класс. Или сделайте нормальную реализацию загрузчика с переопределением `findClass()` и загрузкой из папки по пришедшему имени. Если в коде загружаемых классов используются ещё и  другие классы вашего приложения, а не только системные, то так же нужно передать в  `MyClassLoader` загрузчик классов приложения (для этого есть конструктор [`ClassLoader(ClassLoader parent)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#ClassLoader-java.lang.ClassLoader-)